# How to fix "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')"

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-resources

I am getting the following error when I build my Android App project in Visual studio 2015.

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

These lines are located under:

```
obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml
```

There is 3 entires of it inside the `AndroidManifest file`.

I have downloaded the google play service from the `SDK Manager`.

Should I reference anything to my solution?

I already has `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` Referenced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have create `integer.xml` file inside `value` folder and define your `Integer` to that place it will solve your problem.

Comment: Logical. Thanks Worked!

Comment: @JosephGhassan Beware that doing it this way will require that you update  this integer resource whenever the Google Play version changes otherwise you will be chasing strange bugs...

Answer (score 4):

Try doing and a clean all and check that **ALL** the content under the `obj` has been deleted and then perform a build all.

If that does not work:

I would try removing the `~GooglePlayServices~` nugets/references and re-add *just* the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps`nuget which will bring in the `~Basement` and `~Base` libraries.

You should end up with a generated manifest that only has one reference to `google_play_services_version` and that resource should be picked up from Debug/android/XXX/YYYYYY/ZZZZZ/R.java:

i.e.

```
public static final int google_play_services_version=0x7f070000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added several new packages. One of the package is the reason of the error. I have to check one by one and caught the one causing error. Removing that package is all I need to do to resolve the error.