# No resource found that matches the given name (at value with value @integer/google_play_services_version)” - Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I found unbelieveable that by just adding a component as google play services - maps cause me so many errors on visual studio, I've already gotten the API Key but what really pissed me off, is that just adding a component gives me a god damn headache like this.
I'm a newbie at xamarin.android, I've used sdk manager and I do have google play services installed already.
If i do a BUILD I get this:

[image: Picture of clicking BUILD]

but if I do REBUILD i'll get this:

[image: Picture of clicking REBUILD]

if you need more info please ask me for it, I'm doing a transition from desktop app development to mobile with xamarin, using Visual Studio 2015.
I've spent an entire day its 12:55Am and i felt that Ive gotten to nowhere, ive seen tutorials where this errors wont even appear at all.

Should I reinstall VS 2015???

I would appreciate details in your solutions.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156985/how-to-fix-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with-value

Comment: I've already try it man, I've read that article and tried all, but nothing works!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to my problem, so I'll explain what did I do to solve it.

Firstable the solution shown at the Link provided by Rashed Biswas none of them serve to my purpose, they mainly said to delete bin and obj folder from debug folderm make a clean solution and rebuild, everytime i did that it took me to the same problem, also I'm not a lover of reinstalling VS, I think that take to much time without the certainty of solving my problem, I've done so before and in my experience sometime it solve the problem other time the problem is deeper that cant be solve like that.

So, if you watch my second picture from y post the one with thousands of errors, it tells you to download a repository from a link provided there and replace its content with the folder each error sugested, I thought in doing that for every error but i didnt read calmly the second error where it says:

Reason File C:\blahblahblah.zip is not a zip archive

so, I went to that folder and deleted its entire content, then I made a rebuild and voila errors gone, BUT...
I still had a problem my nuget package manager broke down, everytime I wanted to use it on any Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio 2015 it showed me a message that said:

Description: An exception was thrown while initializing part "NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSSolutionManager".
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSSolutionManager". ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: GetFullVsVersionString must be called on the UI thread.

so, I found this link ay GitHub really helpful link:

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3419

after reading almost all comments this guy "dktechindia", mention NugetFix.Vsix and provided the link to download it:

http://xvs.xamarin.com/patcheddrops/NuGetFixer.vsix

this little tool fix my nuget package manager, now I tried to find more about this tool on internet but i was too tired and honestly i didnt try that hard, but it worked for me, hopefully my experience work for some of you too.

Anyways thanks for those who tried to help me, I hope this knowledge helps someone else.

C ya ppl!!!

Comment: Been looking for a solution for a week! Who would have thought deleting the bin folder would have fixed my problem! I can't thank you enough

Comment: Been there man, I suffered the same scenario many months ago. You're welcome!