# @integer/google_play_services_version Issue Xcode

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

i'm trying to solve this error in Xcode for Mac

> Error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'). (APT0000)

i've read in many forum but i haven't found any solution, 
i'm trying to use ***Google play services cloud messaging GCM*** component in my app, i've added it and this error displays every time i build my app.
i created a `integer.xml` file in `values` folder and set the integer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">0x7f070000</integer>
</resources>
```

i tried `0x7f070000` , `0`, `1`,`4` and so on...

in this way the error disappears, but i have another error now

> java/lang/Object.class) major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version
>   supported by this compiler

if i remove the **GCM** component the error disappears, i tried, without success to update the sdk, clean and build the project. but no way!

can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b)

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156985/how-to-fix-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with-value