# Unable to build game using gradle in unity2017.2

Tags: android, google-play-services, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

**I am trying to build my game using gradle in unity2017.2 i have plugins facebook, google play service and google admobs. but getting the below error. 
Can you help me to remove this error I have searched it on google and tried all solution i found but unable to remove this kindly help me**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleDebug"

stderr[
D:\Frozen Fog\Final\kitcat123\Temp\gradleOut\GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin\build\intermediates\bundles\release\aapt\AndroidManifest.xml:35:28-65: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@Integer/google_play_services_version').


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google\_play\_services\_version')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156985/how-to-fix-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with-value)

Comment: Not same that is for xamarin and i am facing this issue in unity

Comment: do you know someone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when adding facebook sdk package to assets, it creates Facebook SDK folder, and plugins are in it, try this : 
1. Move everything from inside Facebook SDK folder to Assets folder. 
2. Then go to Assets/PlayServicesResolver/AndroidResolver/Force Resolve (Don't know if this is necessary).
It appears that unity couldn't find the path to plugins for android. I lost 5 days in searching the solution.